# ngrouteProvider isn't working in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my code http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3784/

I debugged it for hours and still can't find what's wrong. No error shown in the console. It says the object not found when I go to localhost/myproject/#/action

is this the correct usage for routing?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/action/:index', {
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: 'MainControl'
    });
})
```

Comment: when you go to `myproject/#/action`, you are actually not matching this pattern `/action/:index`, you have to add also `/action` in routes definition to make that work

Comment: maybe the problem is in your server configuration... is it properly set to return only `index.html` for the path `localhost/project`?

Comment: @doodeec yes, what's wrong with that? suppose I can see the # sign at the end of my index.html, but it didn't appear like usual.